# Getting Missing queryFn error when using React query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

here is the code I am using. it doesn't make any sense to me because the error is basically telling me I am not passing it a function when using query but I am. and I am not calling the function directly either. any help would be a appreciated

```jsx
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
//import Posts from './components/Posts'
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import React from "react";

async function fetchPosts() {
  const data = await fetch("http://swapi.dev/api/planetsd");
  return data.json();
}

function App() {
  const { data, status, error } = useQuery(
    "stuffthing",
    async () => await fetchPosts()
  );
  // first argumello\'ent is a string to cache and track the query result
  if (status === "error") {
    console.log(`${error} new error`);
  }
  if (status === "loading") {
    return <div>loading</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error message, in full please

Comment: You appear to be using the deprecated [react-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query) library. You should be using [@tanstack/react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/installation) instead

Comment: I'm most likely following the same tutorial as you, and got exactly the same problem.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco did you use  newest `react-query`?

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the exact same issue and it took me wayyy too long to figure out what was going on.
If you're following the documentation of v3, useQuery would indeed be used as such:

> const { data, status, error } = useQuery("posts", async () => await fetchPosts());

However, in v4 it has changed to take an array as a first parameter:

> const { data, status, error } = useQuery(**["posts"]**, async () => await fetchPosts());

Three hours of my life I'll never get back.

Comment: I was going to answer this, the method expects different parameters across `react-query` versions.
@Phil, I just run `npm install react-query` (not `@tanstack/react-query`) and I got version 4 installed.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco ah, looks like the authors have set up an alias or something like that

Comment: @Phil it could be... given that I'm following a tutorial on the topic, I'm not the most qualified person to answer :)

Comment: Looks like `react-query` is stuck at version 4.0.0. You should have seen a deprecation warning when installing it and should migrate immediately to `@tanstack/react-query`